# Checking if cells are selected or not when button is pressed swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

[image: UI photo]

In this photo as you can see user can turn on or off the switch for each cell. At the end when the user presses the button I need to add the selected cell (the cells that have a switch on) to an array to send it to API.

When the user clicks the button (at the bottom of the screen) I should get the `unitNo` and `personId` and store them in my struct

**My model:**

```
struct Itemm : Codable {
    var unitNo:Int?
    var personId:Int?
}
struct welcome {
    var items : [Itemm?]
}
```

**and I have to send an array like below:**

```
{
  "items": [
    {
      "unitNo": 0,
      "personId": 0
    }
  ]
}
```

I'm some confused as to how I should access the cell data in UIButton with if statement and then storing them. I would be grateful for any help.

**Tableview:**

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "SmsCell") as? SmsTableViewCell

    cell?.PhonNumberLbl.text = data![indexPath.section].contacts[indexPath.row]?.phoneNumber
    cell?.NameLbl.text = data![indexPath.section].contacts[indexPath.row]?.name
    cell?.selectedTF.isOn = (data![indexPath.section].contacts[indexPath.row]?.selected)!

    return cell!
}
```

**API response:**

```
 [
    {
        "contacts": [
            {
                "id": 9827,
                "selected": true,
                "phoneNumber": "09203137745",
                "name": "owner"
            },
            {
                "id": 10159,
                "selected": true,
                "phoneNumber": "08523698522",
                "name": "hff"
            },
            {
                "id": 10161,
                "selected": true,
                "phoneNumber": "09586731218",
                "name": "hjdldue"
            }
        ],
        "unitNo": 1,
        "unitPlaque": "jack",
        "billText": "texttext"
    },
    {
        "contacts": [
            {
                "id": 10145,
                "selected": true,
                "phoneNumber": "09123809556",
                "name": "mmm"
            },
            {
                "id": 10160,
                "selected": true,
                "phoneNumber": "85233366888",
                "name": "ttt"
            }
        ],
        "unitNo": 2,
        "unitPlaque": "mm",
        "billText": "texttext"
    }
]
```

---

I think I didn't clearly explain what I'm looking for.

The first method I call is a `GET` method which gives me the data that I'm presenting in the table. The user could only change the switch, the user can change it as many times as they want until he/she presses the button (at the bottom of the screen).

When the button is pressed, I need to get the hidden data behind each cell and store them in my struct and send it to API which has another method. When the user presses the button I need to extract the 2 properties from the  cells that has a switch on.

**Presenter represents this:**

```
func sendSmsForAllTheMembers(AptId:String , data:[String:Int])
{
    ApiGenerator.request(targetApi: ApartemanService.sendSms(aptId: AptId, data: data), responseModel: Nil.self, success: { (response) in
        if response.response.statusCode == 200 {
            self.view?.SendingSmsSuccess()
        }else {
            do{

                var errorMessage = try response.response.mapString()
                errorMessage = errorMessage.replacingOccurrences(of: "\"", with: "",
                                                                 options: NSString.CompareOptions.literal, range:nil)

                self.view?.SendingSmsFailed(errorMessage: errorMessage)

            }catch let error{
                print(error)
                self.view?.SendingSmsFailed(errorMessage: "error")
            }

        }

    }) { (error) in
        self.view?.SendingSmsFailed(errorMessage: "error")
    }
}
```

Comment: can you provide a code on how you are making the switches ?

Comment: what do mean making the switches? I receive some data from API and it has a selected variable, if that selected variable is true then the switch will be on

Comment: aha so if the data is Selected you need to turn the switch on  ?

Comment: ok, can you provide code on how are you populating the cells in the tableView ? and the data object from the API ?

Comment: noo!!!! if the switch is on I need to return the ID of that cell which is not shown

Comment: @ItanHant if you are populating just on base of API then if you change the switch state and scroll your switch will reset to the value coming from API. To retain the changed state you need to store it

Comment: @Shruti please try to understand what is this guy trying to do,  he is saying "i need to return the id of that cell is not shown" , "i receive some data from API and it has selected variable if that selected variable is true then switch will be on"

Comment: @Tobi i know i am off the question he is asking but i am trying to explain a genuin table view problem to him , as it a switch user can change its state manually also, what if user changed the state and scrolled and then scrolled back. In this case changed state wont be maintained.

Comment: @Shruti I receive the data from API in one method and I show that in this table in this way when the user clicks the button I use another method. the first one is GET and the second one is POST

Comment: add tag to your switch and target, then get your particular switch event indexpath and update your array value

Comment: @Shruti i think my answer is what he is trying to do, else he will downvote me for not understanding what he wants xD

Comment: You may use Custom Cell and write delegate to this Cell

Comment: @AliIhsanURAL so what should I do?

Comment: Create a Xib File ( UITableViewCell ) and in this Cell Class , write a protocol for this event

Comment: I have a custom cell but it is not in the xib , it is in the table view itself

Comment: A side note. The font is a bit too small and the color of the text in navBar doesn't have a good contrast with its background. Che bamazze neveshti 'Ethan Hunt' ro :D

Comment: @Honey I'll fix them later thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SmsCell**

```
var switchHandler: ((Bool)->Void)?

@IBAction func switchChanged(_ sender: UISwitch) {
    self.switchHandler?(sender.isOn)
}
```

**View Controller**

```
var selectedCells = Set<IndexPath>()
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "SmsCell") as! SmsTableViewCell
    let cellData = self.data![indexPath.section]
    let contact = cellData.contacts[indexPath.row]
    cell.PhonNumberLbl.text = contact.phoneNumber
    cell.NameLbl.text = contact.name
    cell.selectedTF.isOn = self.selectedCells.contains(indexPath)
    cell.switchHandler = { (switchState) in
        if switchState {
            self.selectedCells.insert(indexPath)
        } else {
            self.selectedCells.remove(indexPath)
        }
    }
    return cell
}


struct Itemm: Codable {
    let unitNo: Int
    let personId: Int
}

struct Welcome: Codable {
    var items:[Itemm]
}
```

**View Controller**

```
  @IBAction func sendButtonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {

      var items = [[String:Int]]()
for indexPath in self.selectedCells {
    let data = self.data![indexPath.section]
    let contact = data.contacts[indexPath.row]
    items.append(["Number" : data.unitNo, "ID" : contact!.id])
}
let welcome = ["items" : items]
print(welcome)
Presenter.sendSmsForAllTheMembers(AptId: aptId, data: welcome)
    }
```

***the final answer is a combination of the answer that some people gave me here and some that I found it myself***

Answer (score 3):

Your first problem is that you need to store the switch state in your view controller somehow; you can't store it in the cell directly since cells are re-used as your table view scrolls.

While you could store the switch state in your model struct, I would probably not do this, as it makes your struct mutable. I would use a `Set<IndexPath>` to track selections.

Your next problem is knowing when the switch is changed in a cell. You can provide a closure to your `UITableviewCell` subclass to handle this.

**SmsCell**

```
var switchHandler: ((Bool)->Void)?

@IBAction func switchChanged(_ sender: UISwitch) {
    self.switchHandler?(sender.isOn)
}
```

**View Controller**

```
var selectedCells = Set<IndexPath>()

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "SmsCell") as! SmsTableViewCell

    let cellData = self.data![indexPath.section]
    let contact = cellData.contacts[indexPath.row]

    cell.PhonNumberLbl.text = contact.phoneNumber
    cell.NameLbl.text = contact.name
    cell.selectedTF.isOn = self.selectedCells.contains(indexPath)
    cell.switchHandler = { (switchState) in
        if switchState {
            self.selectedCells.insert(indexPath)
        } else {
            self.selectedCells.remove(indexPath)
        }
    }

    return cell
}
```

Your final task is to create struct that you can encode into the required JSON:

```
struct Itemm: Codable {
    let unitNo: Int
    let personId: Int
}

struct Welcome: Codable {
    var items:[Itemm]
}
```

**View Controller**

```
@IBAction func sendButtonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {

   var items = [Itemm]() 
   for indexPath in self.selectedCells {
       let data = self.data![indexPath.section]
       let contact = data.contacts[indexPath.row]
       let newItem = Itemm(unitNo: data.unitNo, personId: contact.id)
       items.append(newItem)
   }
   let welcome = Welcome(items: items)
   // Now you can encode and send welcome
}
```

Comment: at the end where you have said: // Now you can encode and send welcome ,I entered ,Presenter.sendSmsForAllTheMembers(AptId: aptId, data: welcome) and it return an error says: Cannot convert value of type 'welcome' to expected argument type '[String : Int]'

Comment: It looks like that function wants a dictionary. With `Codable` you can just pass your `Welcome` instance to a `JSONEncoder` to get the JSON `Data`. You will need to refactor your code to work with this.

Comment: should I change this part:     var parameterEncoding: ParameterEncoding {
        return URLEncoding.default
    }

Comment: I don’t know. I don’t know what your Sendsms function wants in that dictionary. It is better to create functions that accept specific objects or structs rather than generic dictionaries as it makes your interfaces more well defined and self documenting.

Comment: i'm using alamofire and moya, and that is the code I used for moya

Comment: As I said, I don’t know anything about that. This answers your original question. It sounds like you have a question about how to send a codable struct; I suggest you ask another question.

Comment: As long as I couldn't send this request with this method I cannot confirm this is the 100% functional answer

Answer (score 1):

ok, as far as i got from what are you trying to do,

1- give the switch tag,

inside the

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, 
      cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
      switch.tag = indexPath.row
      switch.addTarget(self, action: #selector(onSwitchValueChanged), for: .touchUpInside)

}
```

And in the didChange Method of the Switch,

```
    func onSwitchValueChanged(_ switch: UISwitch) {
       if switch.on {
       selectedArray.append(dataArray[switch.tag])
    } esle {
      selectedArray.remove(at: switch.tag)
}
```

Comment: I think I didn't clearly explain what I'm looking for. The first method I call Is a get method which gives me the data that I'm presenting in the table. the user could only change the switch. the user could change it as many as they want until he/she presses the button! When the button is pressed, I need to get the hidden data behind each cell and store them in my struct and send it to API which has another method. when the user presses the button I need 2 data from that each cell that has a switch on

Comment: this can give you an idea when you get the selectedArray, you can do whatever you want this code gives you what user selected, "selectedArray" is an empty array you define on top and give it the same data type of your objects and when user click the button you just get this array and fetch its data pretty simple

Comment: i can edit and explain more if you want, just approve my answer when done thanks

Comment: you mean if user randomly changes the switches in automatically add an delete the items from the array?

Comment: and how am I supposed to get the unitNo and personId with this code?

Comment: The selected array contains all objects are selected just send them all it’s already implemented

Comment: what is dataArray and selectedArray?

Comment: data array is your response from server that you are populating the table from, and selected array you make a new array of the same type called that

Comment: sorry but the code doesn't work for me , and only shows error

Comment: you don't copy paste it, dude you understands it

Comment: func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
  let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "SmsCell") as? SmsTableViewCell
  
  func onSwitchValueChanged(_ switch: UISwitch) {
   if (cell?.selectedTF.isOn)! {
    itemsForSms.append(data[cell?.selectedTF.ison])
   } else {
    itemsForSms.remove(at: cell?.selectedTF.ison)
   }
  }
  
  cell?.selectedTF.tag = indexPath.row
    cell?.selectedTF. addTarget(self, action: #selector(onSwitchValueChanged), for: .touchUpInside)

Comment: I even changed everything

Answer (score -1):

You can update your Model objects when switch on/off function and also give switch tag as a `cell.indexpath`.

Update model objects like this Ex :-

```
if switch == on {

 items[switch_tag].unitNo =0 

} else {

  items[switch_tag].unitNo =1 
}
```